# can't upload greater 50MB

Tags: php

i want to upload two files.
here is the script

```
<?
    ini_set('memory_limit', "400M");
    ini_set('file_uploads', "5");
    ini_set('max_execution_time', "900");
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', "400M");
    ini_set('post_max_size', "400M");
?>
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
<input type="file" name="video"  />
<input type="file" name="picture" >
<input type="submit"  class="input" value="Հիշել" />
</form>
```

**form.php:**

```
    <?
ini_set('memory_limit', "400M");
ini_set('file_uploads', "5");
ini_set('max_execution_time', "900");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', "400M");
ini_set('post_max_size', "400M");
        print_r($_FILES);
       //returns Array ( )
    ?>
```

i've asked about this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609073/problem-when-uploading-file/2609103#2609103) , and i've set ini_set(...) as you see, but
when i try to upload the file greater than **50MB**, it doesn't happen.
could you tell me why?

### update

YES, you're true
i've print phpinfo(), and it shows, that upload_max_filesize is still 10MB. but why, if i wrote ini_set()?

Comment: What kind of error messages are you getting?

Comment: @Levi Hackwith there isn't any error. print_r($_FILES); returns an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your php.ini file to see if there is a setting for the maximum upload size. You may not be able to override that setting in your PHP script.

Comment: @Barry Brown i can i check it?

Comment: If you have access to your server's configuration files, yes. On a Linux host, it may be stored in /etc/php.ini or /etc/httpd/conf/php.ini. I'm not sure where it is kept on a Windows machine. Or do what @sologhost suggests: use phpinfo() to see what the settings are.

Answer (score 4):

There could be a restriction set by your web server; for example, you can set an Apache  LimitRequestBody directive that can prevent uploading a large file.

Comment: @JacobM could you give a link, or tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The web server also controls (limits) the upload size. You should verify the maximum upload size in your web server configuration.

Best Regards,
Don

Comment: @Don Dickinson how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

To verify webserver configuration, create a php file with the following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

This will tell you all the configuration that, I believe, Don is talking about.  Upload it to your server, and run it in your browser.

Comment: It's phpinfo(); not php_info();

Answer (score 1):

The person in the previous question was wrong.  `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are marked as `PHP_INI_PERDIR`:

```
upload_max_filesize     "2M"    PHP_INI_PERDIR      PHP_INI_ALL in PHP <= 4.2.3.
post_max_size   "8M"    PHP_INI_PERDIR      PHP_INI_SYSTEM in PHP <= 4.2.3. Available since PHP 4.0.3.
```

-- PHP Manual, [Description of core php.ini directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

`PHP_INI_PERDIR` can not be changed with `ini_set`:

> Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess
> or httpd.conf

-- PHP Manual page "[Where a configuration setting may be set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)"

Use one of his other methods to change the value instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply ini_set all php configuration variables, some of them should be set before processing any php file.

You can change them in `php.ini` or in `.htaccess` like this:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value post_max_size 50M
  php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some web servers, some `ini_set()` values are ignored. Contact your host, sometimes they will let you upload a custom `php.ini` file with the maximum upload size you require.

Answer (score 0):

Smply create a php.ini file in your /public_html/ folder or if it already exists then edit them.

```
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

that is it.