# PHP: Uploading a .ogz-File

Tags: php, upload

I'm trying to upload an .ogz-file, but if I do so, on the submit-page, the $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'] is empty, what makes me think there are some troubles moving the file...

How can this happen? And what can I do now?

thx, flo

EDIT: .ogz is a map format in the game Sauerbraten (www.sauerbraten.org)

Comment: Have you tried to print_r($_FILES) to make sure you are accessing the array correctly?

Comment: yes, and thats why i'm sure the tmp_name is empty

Comment: Can you post your code? Does anything change if you rename the file to `FILENAME.ogz.txt` and then try to upload?

Comment: Do other file types work? Make sure you try a file that's just as large as the ogz file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set. Then with `var_dump` or `print_r` check the actual contents of the `$_FILES` array. Also pay attention to the error members of the array.

**Added:** The PHP manual has [a section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) explaining the error codes. Note that the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` form member is [some kind of crap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381364/max-file-size-in-php-whats-the-point) and you should ignore it and not use it.

**Added 2:** Oh, and, naturally, the form must have `method="POST"` set.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your form is enctype="multipart/form-data"