# Min Size of The File to be Uploaded

Tags: html

I am trying to find that does **HTML** provide any option in `<input type='file' />` to set the minimum and maximum size of file being uploaded.

Comment: A *minimum* file size seems odd to enforce; how can you know the smallest, most optimised possible encoding of your data beforehand?

Comment: @deceze I just want my form not to upload a file of size 0 bytes

Comment: Since there's no way you can ultimately prevent that, you need to handle that case on the server anyway; and since there's no real harm done (contrary to *too large* files), I don't see the need for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. But theis attribute is for the server side SOFT impose of the limit.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1024" />
```

The value is in bytes.

You should use [HTML File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) to restrain size of the uploads. That is the preferred way.

Comment: How can I do it for the minimum value.like No file size should be less then 1 byte

Comment: [`MAX_FILE_SIZE` doesn't do anything *in HTML*.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1381364/476)

Comment: @CharlieH isn't there any attribute for minimum ??

Comment: As @deceze has mentioned, browser doesn't do anything for this attribute. It really is for your PHP script to impose a SOFT limit. You can use your own attribute MIN_FILE_SIZE and consider that in your PHP. HTML File API is the real deal.Answer updated.