# PhpMailer doesn't send Email with .pdf file attached

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I want to send a file via PhpMailer. If the file has extension .txt or .png ecc.. It sends me the email with the file (it works) but if I want to send a .pdf I don't receive the email ... this is a part of my PHP code:

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$Residence = $_POST['Residence'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];

$Name = filter_var($Name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Surname = filter_var($Surname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$Email = filter_var($Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$Residence = filter_var($Residence, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);;
$Phone = filter_var($Phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);;

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "xxx"; //account with which you want to send mail. Or use this account. i dont care :-P
$mail->Password = "xxx"; //this account's password.
$mail->SetFrom('xxx');
$mail->Port = "465";
$mail->isSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$rec1="xxx"; //receiver. email addresses to which u want to send the mail.
$mail->AddAddress($rec1);
$mail->Subject  = "Eventbook";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body     = "<h1>Contact from Website</h1>
<ul>
<li>Nome: {$Name}</li>
<li>Cognome: {$Surname}</li>
<li>Comune di residenza: {$Residence}</li>
<li>Email: {$Email}</li>
<li>Telefono: {$Phone}</li>
</ul>";
$mail->WordWrap = 200;
$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['curriculum']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['curriculum']['name']);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent!.';
$errore = $mail->ErrorInfo;
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo  //Fill in the document.location thing
'<script type="text/javascript">
                        if(confirm("Your mail has been sent"))
                        document.location = "/";
        </script>';
}
```

This is the JS script with ajax:

```
var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Name', $('#Name').val());
        formData.append('Surname', $('#Surname').val());
        formData.append('Residence', $('#Residence').val());
        formData.append('Email', $('#Email').val());
        formData.append('Phone', $('#Phone').val());
        formData.append('Curriculum', $('#Curriculum')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "scripts/register.php",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (Curriculum) {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
```

This is the HTML file input part:

```
<input type="file" name="Curriculum" id="Curriculum" style="display: none;" class="form__input" />
           <label for="Curriculum" id="LabelCurriculum" class="form__input" style="background-color: white; display: block; width: 100%; padding: 20px; font-family: Roboto; -webkit-appearance: none; border: 0; outline: 0; transition: 0.3s;">Click to upload</label>
```

It seems that It can't upload due to its size maybe ... because I uploaded .txt and .png of 50KB but the .pdf is 1MB

UPDATE: When I debug I can see that the file is uploaded , so I think that it don't send the email... why????

Comment: Have you checked $_FILES['curriculum'] before you use it in PHPMailer if it's really uploaded?

Comment: How can I do that? Is there a js function to check it before I send my form via ajax?

Comment: Can you post your javascript/ajax code?

Comment: Please remove the credentials with less meaningful data like `xxx`, `(hidden)` etc.

Comment: Added in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use values directly from the `$_FILES` superglobal as they are potentially forgeable. You must validate them using the built-in `move_uploaded_file` or `is_uploaded_file` functions. The [PHP docs on handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) are excellent, so do what they say.

Base your code on the [send file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) which uses `move_uploaded_file` before using the file. It's also a good idea to not use user-supplied filenames so as to avoid the possibility of file overwrite attacks - in the example you'll see it uses a hash of the filename (which will always be safe) to avoid doing that.

It's a good idea to check return values from critical functions - `addAttachment()` returns false if it can't read the file you ask it to read, for example:

```
if (!$mail->addAttachment($filename, 'file.pdf')) die('Could not read file!');
```

Look at the file upload size limit set in your PHP config, and mirror that in your form - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381364/max-file-size-in-php-whats-the-point). If you exceed this limit, you may find that you still have an entry in your `$_FILES` array, but it may point to an empty or non-existent file, which is another reason to validate and check return values. You can `var_dump($_FILES)` to see exactly what your script is receiving - it may not contain what you think it should.

I can see that you've based your code on a very old example, so make sure you're running the latest version of PHPMailer too.